# wpf square resizable grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a photo gallery component that consists of a `Grid` inside a `ScrollViewer` It should be resizeable, but photo cell must remain square, and vertical gaps should be the same size as horizontal. So I am trying to bind row sizes to columns' actual sizes:

```
<ScrollViewer>
        <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Name="column" Width="216*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Name="gap" Width="4*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="216*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="216*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="216*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=column, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=gap, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=column, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=gap, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=column, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=gap, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=column, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

But the resulting grid looks like [image: Grid]
[image: Grid]

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to make cells always square?

Comment: ColumnDefinition's ActualWidth is not a dependency property, so binding to it doesn't make sence, since the value will always be 0

Answer (score 0):

I think grid is not good control for this, because if you write photo gallery component you need wrap items after resize.

Best way use ListBox with custom style(use WrapPanel as ItemsHost element).
ListBox:

```
 <ListBox 
      Style="{StaticResource PhotoListStyle}"  
      SelectionMode="Extended" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
 </ListBox>
```

Custom Style:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" x:Key="PhotoListStyle">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" >
            <WrapPanel Margin="5" IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                       ItemHeight="{Binding ElementName=32}" 
                       ItemWidth="{Binding ElementName=32" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

English is not my native language